# Large space on page after inserting tikz figures wrapped in minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, minipage

I'm trying to insert four tikz figures inline with minipages, but there's an unexpected space between the figures and the title. This happens regardless of how many figures I put or how large the figures are, seemingly. Why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{February 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Title}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
            \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=middle,
                    grid = major,
                    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                    xlabel=$x_1$,
                    ylabel=$x_2$,
                    xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                    ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
            \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
            \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
            -1 0
            0 1
            };
            \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
            \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=middle,
                    grid = major,
                    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                    xlabel=$x_1$,
                    ylabel=$x_2$,
                    xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                    ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
            \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
            \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
            -1 0
            0 1
            };
            \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
            \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=middle,
                    grid = major,
                    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                    xlabel=$x_1$,
                    ylabel=$x_2$,
                    xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                    ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
            \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
            \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
            -1 0
            0 1
            };
            \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
            \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=middle,
                    grid = major,
                    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                    xlabel=$x_1$,
                    ylabel=$x_2$,
                    xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                    ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
            \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
            \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
            -1 0
            0 1
            };
            \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please always post a complete, compilable example rather than a fragment. Float handling depends, for example, on your class.  However, almost certainly you should remove the `figure` environment. If you need a caption, use `capt-of` or `caption` and then say `\captionof...`. A figure is a float. It can only go in certain places: top of the page, bottom of the page, float page etc. You could try adding the placement option `[htbp]` to the `figure` environment first if you prefer. I've never had any luck with it, but others seem to.

Comment: Thanks @cfr! After removing the figure environment the figures end up at the very top of the page, overlapping with the title. How do I fix this?

Comment: A proper example would make it much easier to help you. You can try altering the vertical alignment of the `minipage`s using the optional argument. The default is `c` for centring. `t` may work better.

Comment: @Jess, see my answer on this question which you ask little before )http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294755/two-captions-under-four-figures-wrapped-in-minipages/). If you will tested it, you will get images on the top of pages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Two captions under four figures wrapped in minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294755/two-captions-under-four-figures-wrapped-in-minipages) I obtain the following result:

[image]

Regarding to mentioned answer I only part of your preamble from MWE in question. For completeness, let be repeated the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\title{my article}
\author{me}
\date{February 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Title}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

&         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption A}
\label{fig:my_label-A}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
&
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {-x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,-1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption B}
    \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```