# Two captions under four figures wrapped in minipages

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, minipage

I have four figures, and I'd like to have two captions centered under each group of two figures rather than one caption under all four figures (see image below). If I try inserting a caption after the first two minipages, however, all the figure alignment gets messed up. How can this be done properly?[image]

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % + +
    \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\quad\quad
    % + -
    \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {-x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,-1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that you like to have something like this:

[image]

To obtain this picture I did the following:

- use only two mini-pages, each for one tabular environment
- in tabular environments put your images
- slightly change your image -- made them smaller and omit canvas transformation (it can be tricky)
- in each mini-page put a caption

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

&         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption A}
\label{fig:my_label-A}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {0};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
&
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                grid = major,
                xmin=-2, xmax=2,
                ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                xlabel=$x_1$,
                ylabel=$x_2$,
                xtick={-2,-1,0,...,2},
                ytick={-2,-1,0,...,2}]
        \addplot [thin, samples=100] {-x};
        \addplot [only marks, mark = +, color = red] table {
        -1 0
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark = -, color = blue] table {
        0 1
        };
        \draw [-latex, red, thick] (0,0) -- (-1,-1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption B}
    \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```